# There is no overloaded version of 'RequestPermissions' that can be called with these arguments giving more then one permisssion

Tags: android, mobile, android-permissions, delphi-11-alexandria

with Delphi 10 i used a procedure to give android app multiple permissions on a onCreate Event:

```
  var
  permBatt, permRead, permWrite, permBlue, permAccess, permCoarse: string;
begin
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}

  // Request permissions
  permBatt := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
  permRead := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
  permWrite := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
  permBlue := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.BLUETOOTH);
  permAccess := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
  permCoarse := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([permBatt, permRead, permWrite, permBlue, permAccess, permCoarse], PermissionRequestResult);

 {$ENDIF}
```

now in delphi 11 Alexandria I receive a compiler error

```
[DCC Error] data.main.pas(237): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'RequestPermissions' that can be called with these arguments
```

I tried use the new singnature of PermissionService.RequestPermission passing a procedure as a paramether and using the new Delphi constants:

```
const
  permBatt = 'android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS';
  permRead = 'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE';
  permWrite = 'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE';
  permBlue  = 'android.permission.BLUETOOTH';
  permAccess = 'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION';
  permCoarse = 'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION';
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}

  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([permBatt, permRead, permWrite, permBlue, permAccess, permCoarse ],
  procedure(const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>)
      begin
        if (Length(AGrantResults) = 1) and (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
          TDialogService.ShowMessage('OK permessi')
      else
        begin
          TDialogService.ShowMessage('Location permission not granted');
        end;
      end);
  {$ENDIF}
```

but the error is still there, any idea? Thank you so moutch

Answer (score 2):

I found the right solution and i hope it'll help

```
procedure TMainData.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
permBatt = 'android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS';
permRead = 'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE';
permWrite = 'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE';
permBlue  = 'android.permission.BLUETOOTH';
permAccess = 'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION';
permCoarse = 'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION';
begin

{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([permBatt,permRead, permWrite, permBlue, permAccess, permCoarse],
    procedure(const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray)
    begin
      if (Length(AGrantResults) = 1) and (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
        { activate or deactivate the location sensor }
      else
      begin
       TDialogService.ShowMessage('Devi dare il permesso alla localizzazione esplicitamente');
      end;
    end);

 {$ENDIF}
end
```